# Using TFRecords for images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use TFRecords to serialized a bunch of `PNG` files. for I took a look into inception [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py). the give example is for `RGB JPEG` files, since my files are in grayscale,  I had to change  the code. 
but I've managed to  generate the records files. 
The problem is when I try to read them:

```
def getImage(filename):
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # convert filenames to a queue for an input pipeline.
    filenameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],num_epochs=None)

    # object to read records
    recordReader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    # read the full set of features for a single example
    key, fullExample = recordReader.read(filenameQ)

    # parse the full example into its' component features.
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        fullExample,
        features={
            'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/colorspace': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/channels':  tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
            'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value='')
        })

    # now we are going to manipulate the label and image features
    label = features['image/class/label']
    image_buffer = features['image/encoded']
    # Decode the PNG 
    with tf.name_scope('decode_img',[image_buffer], None):
        # decode
        image = tf.image.decode_png( image_buffer, channels=1)

        # and convert to single precision data type
        image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    # cast image into a single array, where each element corresponds to the greyscale
    # value of a single pixel.

    image =tf.reshape([None, img_height*img_width])# here is the problem 

    label=tf.stack(tf.one_hot(label-1, numberOFclasses))
    return label, image
```

the problem is  the  reshape line,the program crashes when I try it this .
this how it's been used:

```
with tf.name_scope('decode_img',[image_buffer], None):
            # decode
            image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)

            # and convert to single precision data type
            image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
        # cast image into a single array, where each element corresponds to the greyscale
        # value of a single pixel.
        # the "1-.." part inverts the image, so that the background is black.
        image=tf.reshape(1-tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image),[img_height*img_width])
```

which make sens since, when the file are RGB. but I have only 1 channel so the file are already grayscale.

Comment: Should be  : image =tf.reshape(image, [img_height*img_width])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `tf.reshape([None, img_height*img_width])`. First of all there is no first parameter (what exactly you are trying to reshape). It should be your `image`. Also most probably you want to reshape it in this way: `tf.reshape(image, [img_height, img_width])`.

Not related to your problem, but why do you need so many features in your TFRecord file?

Comment: thanks for reply, indeed this was my mistake.  I don't need all the mentioned features, just wanted to keep it as the reference code mentioned in inception !

Comment: your answer solve the error, but the result is pretty weird, please take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901432/weird-accuracy-result-in-convnn-tensorflow